# How do you reference a maven profile in a dependency?

Tags: java, maven

I have a jar file that is built only as a profile. How do I reference that in a `<dependency/>` block? Let's say it's groupId is com.mycompany, artifactId is test-jar, version is 2.0 and profile is customBuild.

Answer (score 0):

From the project you are building run `mvn install`, which will install the jar locally in your `.m2` directory. Then you can reference it as a regular dependency using

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
        <artifactId>test-jar</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

in your dependent projects.